# I am trying to write a code to convert an 8 bit grayscale image into 7 bit image.

Tags: java, image-processing

Since 8 bit image have intensity values 0 to 255, I want to convert the intensity values from 0 to 127. How do I map the intensity values in java.

Comment: Post some code. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This will help someone here to help you with your problem.

Comment: A hint: 7 bits has half the values of 8 bits.

Comment: why would you do that? there is no 7bit image format anyway. you give away half your resolution for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple division by 2!

```
myimage.getRaster().setSample(x, y, myimage.getRaster().getSample(x, y)/2) ;
```

The values are then distributed on [0,127], but the encoding is still on byte.

Comment: Assume you meant `getSample()`, and `>>> 1` might be better than `/ 2`.

Comment: Yes, stupid copy/paste. And yes for the ">> 1", I always use it, but most people are not confortable with, so I never use it on SO.

Comment: Explanation: gray scale is linear 0=black upto max=white. So taking (0, 1) -> 0, (2, 3) -> 1, (4, 5) -> 2, etcetera, maps similar brightness to one, in order. One might consider a bit of gamma correction, for instance if 0-16 all aspect black.

Answer (score 0):

Just divide each pixel value by 2.

Comment: Divide by 2 worked... Thanks...